# Neo4j java: Traversal from multiple start points

Tags: neo4j

my task in Neo4j 2.0 embedded is to find the paths from multiple nodes to the root of the tree, in which all nodes are located.

Thus, if we assume I have start nodes A, B, and C, I'd like to find paths

```
A-->...-->root
B-->...-->root
C-->...-->root
```

For this task, I defined a TraversalDescription which works just fine when applied to each of the start nodes individually. Now I saw that the TraversalDescription's traverse method can not only take one start node but multiple. So I put all my start nodes into an array and passed this array to the traverse method like this:

```
Node[] startNodes = new Node[3];
startNodes[0] = node1;
...
Traverser traverse = td.traverse(startNodes);
for (Path p : traverse)
  System.out.println(p);
```

Here I expected to get all the paths back I sketched above. However, I only seem to get the path for the first element in the start node array, i.e. only one path although there exists one different path for each start node.

Now my question is: What is wrong? My intention of how the method should work or am I just using it incorrectly?

Thank you very much for answers, ideas and hints!

Comment: My gut feeling says that this might be related to the uniqueness setting of your TraveralDescription.

Comment: And your guts aren't failing you, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does your full traversal description look like? I'm guessing you're using the wrong uniqueness setting. The default is NODE_GLOBAL, which can only allow the traversal to visit any node once. I would recommend using use NODE_PATH.