# Neo4j: How to return multiple paths from different starting nodes

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I have a question similar to
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514056/neo4j-java-traversal-from-multiple-start-points) but I am using the c# with the neo4jClient instead of the Java.

I can get the parent path of a given node with the following code but it becomes a performance bottle neck when trying to find the parent path of many nodes.  **What I would like is a way to call the graph database once with a list of node keys and get back a list of parent paths.  So that I can return a dictionary of results instead of a single list.**

Any help accomplishing this would be greatly appreciated!  Also if my original cypher query can be improved I'm open to that as well.

```
    public IEnumerable<IGenericEntity> GetPath(string entityCompositeKey, GraphRelationship relationship)
    {
        var entity = new GenericEntity();
        entity.setCompositeKey(entityCompositeKey);
        var pathToRoot = new List<GenericEntity>(){ entity };

        var query = new CypherFluentQuery(graphClient)
                    .Match("p = (current)-[r:" + relationship.Name + "*0..]->()")
                    .Where((IGenericEntity current) => current.CompositeKey == entityCompositeKey)
                    .Return(() => Return.As<IEnumerable<GenericEntity>>("nodes(p)"))
                    .OrderByDescending("length(p)")
                    .Limit(10);

        var queryText = query.Query.QueryText;
        var paramText = query.Query.QueryParameters;
        if (query.Results != null)
        {
            var graphResults = query.Results.FirstOrDefault();
            if (graphResults != null && graphResults.ToList().Count > 0)
            {
                pathToRoot = graphResults.ToList();
            }
        }
        return pathToRoot;
    }
```

Comment: Do you only want the Nodes back?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I'm not sure of - and it's most likely how my test DB is setup.

To answer the initial question of how to pass in multiple start nodes - that's probably best approached using the [`UNWIND`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-unwind.html) operator, which in `Neo4jClient` is used like so:

```
var enumerable = new string[] { "a", "b" }
client.Unwind(enumerable, "item"). /*The rest*/
```

Obvs, if you place that in the top of your current query you'll get a *monster* set of nodes back, and you won't know which `Root` entity refers to which, *soo*... let's do some projecting...

To project, we must have something to project into:

```
public class Result {
    public GenericEntity Root { get; set; }
    public List<GenericEntity> Nodes { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
}
```

This will contain the `Root` node, and the path to it, now to fill.

```
public IEnumerable<Result> GetPath(IEnumerable<string> rootKeys, GraphRelationship relationship)
{
    var query = new CypherFluentQuery(Client)
                .Unwind(rootKeys, "entityRootKey")
                .Match(string.Format("p = (root)-[r:{0}*0..]->()", relationship.Name))
                .Where("root.CompositeKey = entityRootKey")
                .With("{Root:root, Nodes: nodes(p), Length: length(p)} as res")
                .Return((res) => res.As<Result>())
                .OrderByDescending("res.Length")
                .Limit(10);

    var results = query.Results;
    return results;
}
```

I'm not using `.Where` with a parameter creating `Func<T>` this is because the parameter is created in the `.Unwind` statement.

Usage wise - something like this:

```
var res = GetPath(new[] {"a", "b"}, new GraphRelationship {Name = "RELATED"});
foreach (var result in res)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{result.Root.CompositeKey} => {result.Length}");
    foreach (var node in result.Nodes)
        Console.WriteLine($"\t{node.CompositeKey}");
}
```